# networking question

Tags: networking

can anybody tell me who is this dhclient  14757      root    6u  IPv4 112852      0t0  UDP *:bootpc  in my firewall scan ??

```
graigster@graigster-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo lsof +M -i4
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
avahi-dae   799     avahi   12u  IPv4  19441      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
avahi-dae   799     avahi   14u  IPv4  19443      0t0  UDP *:35779 
dnsmasq     953    nobody    4u  IPv4  20247      0t0  UDP graigster-Inspiron-1545:domain 
dnsmasq     953    nobody    5u  IPv4  20248      0t0  TCP graigster-Inspiron-1545:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq     953    nobody   11u  IPv4 112910      0t0  UDP *:55166 
cupsd     10170      root   11u  IPv4  83360      0t0  TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
cups-brow 10172      root    8u  IPv4  83378      0t0  UDP *:ipp 
firefox   14514 graigster  212u  IPv4 113804      0t0  TCP graigster-Inspiron-1545:47722->ec2-52-27-163-157.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome-gn 14592 graigster   59u  IPv4 108057      0t0  TCP graigster-Inspiron-1545:33022->104.25.75.19:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
chrome-gn 14592 graigster   91u  IPv4 109229      0t0  UDP localhost:39437->graigster-Inspiron-1545:domain 
chrome-gn 14592 graigster   96u  IPv4 108075      0t0  TCP graigster-Inspiron-1545:60860->ec2-54-186-218-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
dhclient  14757      root    6u  IPv4 112852      0t0  UDP *:bootpc
```

Answer (score 0):

`dhclient` handles DHCP negotiation for your IP address on a dynamically-assigned network, such as a typical home router or a network where devices are continually connected or disconnected.  It's listening because that's how your computer knows how to negotiate traffic with the local network, but the computer also does negotiation at the end of an IP lease to get a new one - this is why it's listening.  It's usually not something to worry yourself over.

If you want to protect your system, you'll need to block all ports that you don't want remote access to, and permit traffic related to established connections or related to currently active or new outgoing connections.  This helps to shield the service from unexpected traffic; however, without knowing what firewall you're using or anything else, it's impossible to be more specific with whether your system is "secure" for this.

Also, `lsof` isn't a firewall scan - it's just a list of what's listening on your computer for additional connections, and such.  You shouldn't rely solely on `lsof` for determining the 'security' of your system.